# Как вывести пользователю 5xx ошибку на Vue Js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

У меня есть REST API и JS библиотека для работы с API. Я использую ее в секции `<script>`

Например так:

```
addItemToCart(variation) {
    carts.add(variation).then(response => {
        if (response.bodyText == "anonymous") {
            window.location.href = "/login"
        } else if (response.bodyText == variation.id) {
            this.snackbar = true
        }
    })          
}
```

UPD:

Пример библиотеки:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)

const cart = Vue.resource('/api/carts/{id}');

export default {
    get: () => cart.get(),
    getOne: id => cart.get({id}),
    add: (body) => cart.save(body),
    update: (id, body) => cart.update({id}, body),
    remove: id => cart.remove({id}),
}
```

Теперь я бы хотел уведомить пользователя, если на сервере возникла какая-то ошибка. Каким образом я могу это сделать?

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: @T0hich71 VueResource

Answer (score 1):

```
addItemToCart(variation) {
    carts.add(variation).then((res, rej) => {
        if (res) {
            if (response.bodyText == "anonymous") {
                window.location.href = "/login"
            } else if (response.bodyText == variation.id) {
                this.snackbar = true
            }
        } else if (rej) {
            console.log(rej); // здесь ваш код, обрабатывающий ошибку получения данных с бэка
        }
    })          
}
```